# Pandas split a row into 4 distinct rows while splitting a column string in 4

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` that looks as such

```
df
    A B C
    0 2 5A5A5A5A5A5A5A5A5A5A5A5A5A5A5A5A
```

I would like to generate the following

```
A B C         Offset
0 2 5A5A5A5A  0
0 2 5A5A5A5A  1
0 2 5A5A5A5A  2
0 2 5A5A5A5A  3
```

This is my non scalable and slow solution when applied over millions of rows:

```
def splitequal(my_str):
    splits = [my_str[x:x+8] for x in range(0,len(my_str),8)]
    return splits

def tondata(row):
    offset = row['Offset']
    return row['Splits'][offset]

d = {'A': [0],
     'B': [2],
     'C': ["5A5A5A5A5A5A5A5A5A5A5A5A5A5A5A5A"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=['A','B','C'])

#Replicate the row 4 times
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.as_matrix(),4,0),columns=['A','B','C'])

# Create the offset column to create 4 substrings
df2['Offset'] = df2.reset_index()['index'] % 4

#Split the string and create an array of 4 strings
df2['Splits'] = df2['C'].apply(splitequal)

#assign each substrings in the array to the 4 different offsets
df2['C'] = df2.apply(tondata,axis=1)

del(df2['Splits'])
print df2

  A  B         C  Offset
0  0  2  5A5A5A5A       0
1  0  2  5A5A5A5A       1
2  0  2  5A5A5A5A       2
3  0  2  5A5A5A5A       3
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Does the string have arbitrary length?

Comment: No. It is always a 32 character string

Comment: Oh, now this makes stuff heaps easier :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
# Get unique index on the data frame
df = df.reset_index()

# Slice the column, concatenate the results together and rename the columns
splitted = pd.concat([
    df["C"].str.slice(i * 8, (i + 1) * 8) for i in range(4)
], axis=1)
splitted.columns = [0, 1, 2, 3]

# Unstack to get a single column with offsets as first index level
unstacked = splitted.unstack()

# Make the new index level an ordinary column
with_offset_col = unstacked.reset_index(level=0)

# Merge this together with the original frame again
pd.merge(df, with_offset_col, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

This code executes in 4.1s on my machine.

Comment: I think you mean 4.1ms. I tested your code against my original attempt. Seems like my attempt is faster as it runs in 2.9ms vs. 4.6ms for your solution.

Comment: That is 4s for a million rows. Testing it on a single row measures only overhead.